# Flip Canvas upside-down while preserving onTouchEvent method

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas

I have created a bar graph by drawing rectangles on a canvas. The only problem is that graph is upside down. I tried using the following code to flip the canvas right from the start, but this affects the onTouchEvent method in a weird way:

```
public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
            int width = super.getWidth();
            int height = super.getHeight();
                canvas.scale(1f, -1f,
                       width * 0.5f, height * 0.5f);
                mCanvas = canvas;
                super.onDraw(canvas);
....//more code after that
```

If the code above is implemented, the graph is shown properly. However, the x & y coordinates of the rectangles are inverted. This means that if I click the top of the canvas where there is no shape, the onTouchEvent method is still fired off because the point is where the rectangle would have been if the canvas wasn't flipped.

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event) {
             super.onTouchEvent(event);

                int x = (int)event.getX();
                int y = (int)event.getY();
                xStored = x; yStored=y;
                if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

               }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                   System.out.println("Touching down!");
                   if(!drawNew){
                       for(Rect rect : rectangles){
                            if(rect.contains(x,y)){
                                System.out.println("Touched Rectangle, start activity."+x+","+y);
                                drawNew = true; 

                                invalidate();
                            }else{

                            }
                   }

                    }else{
                        drawNew = false; 

                        invalidate();
                    }
               }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

               }
              this.postInvalidate();
             return true;
          }
```

Whats the best way to flip the canvas upside-down while still preserving the onTouchEvent method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is better to move and rotate the object on the canvas, rather than rotating the canvas itself.